# Got Runtime Error after reinstalling Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, runtimeexception

got this Runtime Error after reinstalling my Android Studio Version -
but I changed nothing in the code - before it works - any idea?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                            Process: com.google.process.gapps, PID: 5759
                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gsf.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5 SQLITE_BUSY): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7035)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6569)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6464)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:220)
                                at                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6464) 
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:220) 
                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860) 
                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403) 
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

I have changed to

```
 ext {
        compose_version = '1.4.3'
        compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'
    }
```

Now I got this error

```
Starting background (first=true): ServiceRecord{65e8b6a u0 com.google.android.gms/.icing.service.IndexWorkerService}
                            java.lang.RuntimeException: here
                                at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.startServiceInnerLocked(ActiveServices.java:788)
                                at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.startServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:716)
                                at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.startServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:480)
                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startService(ActivityManagerService.java:14005)
                                at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2155)
                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2763)
                                at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed Electric Eel latest version right? If so, you need to add contents of jbr folder into jre folder, ensure that they match.

Comment: I have copied jbr to jre - same result

Answer (score 0):

I changed  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '**1.8.10**' in build.gradle

because it needs version 1.8.10

now it works